# C(++) malloc confusion

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I'm just not getting any further with allocating memory for arrays in C and mainly C++.
I've looked for examples but there aren't any useful ones for me out there, at least it seems so.

So if I have a typedef here like this:

```
typedef struct
{
int x;
int y;
} Coordinate;

Coordinate* myList;
```

And I have an array of the type `Coordinate` too, how do I append items to it dynamically.
All I know is that I have to use `malloc` and later `free` in C and `new` / `delete` in C++.
(Malloc scares the hell out of me)

So what I was aiming for is a function like this:

```
void AddSomething ( int x, int y )
{
// myList malloc/new magic here
}
```

My question is:

- How does the line that allocates new memory for myList and then adds the new item to it have to look like?
  **Could you please show me a *working* example for C and C++?**
- How exactly does malloc in C work? There are some things about it that I'm not familiar with (there is some sort of pointer before the function, and the variable that is allocated is set to `malloc`s return value)

Comment: Do you want to dynamically allocate an array whose length is fixed after allocation, or do you want to use a variable-length array (i.e., a linked list or similar)? Also, there is a world of difference between how you'd do this in C or C++. That is, with C++, you could just use `std::vector` which will do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Also, you'd ideally have a constructor `Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y)` in C++.

Comment: The typedef serves no purpose here.  It is irrelevant to the question, and is obfuscatory cruft.  You don't need a typedef to define a struct.

Comment: SO is not a good place to cover `malloc()` and related functions in general; it's far better suited to answer specific questions.  Your specific question is actually a fairly complicated one, and not well suited for a "give me the code" example.  If you can stick to C++, use `vector<>`s.

Comment: @William:  It's common practice in C, since otherwise he'd have to use `struct Coordinate` rather than `Coordinate` (at least in C90; I don't know all the C99 changes).  The `typedef` is unnecessary in C++.

Comment: You seem to confuse terms (and maybe concepts). Is it really a _list_ which you want to store or rather a dynamically allocated _array_? And do you want to use `malloc()`/`free()` (you probably shouldn't, in C++) or do you want to use dynamic memory as it should be done in C++ (with `new`/`delete`)?

Comment: If you are trying to change the size of allocated memory (for instance to make an array larger), use `realloc` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: @David: Note that the question is tagged `C++`, not `C`, so the `typedef` is _not_ appropriate.

Comment: @sbi: Yes, but the OP says "Could you please show me a working example for C and C++?" and asks the question in a way that suggests that he's confusing C and C++.

Comment: @failat Also first make sure you understand the basics -- what is dynamic memory allocation, and when to use it; what is heap and stack; etc.

Answer (score 14):

Use vector to do the job.

```
#include <vector>

typedef struct
{
int x;
int y;
} Coordinate;

std::vector<Coordinate> coordinates;

Coordinate newCoord;
newCoord.x = 1;
newCoord.y = 1;

coordinates.push_back(newCoord);
```

**Additional Information:**
To understand malloc/free and new/delete you might read chapter

13: Dynamic Object Creation

in Bruce Eckels [Thinking C++ Volume 1](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html#HTMLFormat). Its a book that can be downloaded for free.

Answer (score 5):

For C, the following will create a list containing a single Coordinate:

```
myList = malloc(sizeof(Coordinate));
```

If you want to allocate an array of size n, you do the following:

```
myList = malloc(n * sizeof(Coordinate));
```

In C++, the code for an array of size n looks like this:

```
myList = new Coordinate[n];
```

For the C++ case, your class must have a default constructor, which the `Coordinate` class has implicitly. However for C++ I'd strongly suggest using a `std::vector<Coordinate>` instead of a manually managed array.

As an aside, you can use `malloc()` to allocate memory in C++ as well, but it only allocates raw memory whereas using new will also trigger a call to the constructor(s). In the case of your struct, there is no difference as it's a POD structure and doesn't require a constructor. Also, keep in mind that if you allocate memory in C++ using `malloc()`, you have to use `free()` to free it; if you are using `new` you need to use `delete` - mixing the two can lead to very interesting results that are not amusing to debug. With `new`, you'll also have to ensure that you match the correct invocation type. Anything created using `new` needs to be cleaned up with `delete` and anything created with array new as in my example above needs to be deleted using `delete[]`.

Comment: Don't forget to use `delete []`, not just `delete`!

Comment: A `void *` is correctly converted to any object pointer type without a cast - in fact one should *not* cast the return value of `malloc` in C.  I would write the above as `myList = malloc(sizeof *myList);`

Comment: @Fred Larson - thanks for the reminder, just updated the answer

Comment: @Alok, thanks for pointing this out, my C is a little rusty. Fixed examples accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

For any question like this, the first reply has to be another question. Specifically, is there some *really* good reason you can't use an `std::vector`? Unless you really, truly, absolutely *can't*, that's the right thing to do.

Otherwise, your only real choice is to write (yet another) imitation of `std::vector`. Though I don't know you personally, experience indicates that what you write probably won't be as good.

Answer (score 1):

> Malloc scares the hell out of me

Being wary of hand managed dynamic memory is a good idea---there are lots of chances to make mistakes doing that; hard to debug mistakes---but no need to be frightened.

What `malloc` does is **asks the OS for a piece of memory at least THIS big**. That's all. <sub>You have to use pointers to keep track of it because the compiler doesn't know what memory the OS will choose for you, and so can't connect a variable name to the place at compile time.</sub>

What `free` does is **tell the OS, I'm done with THIS memory and won't be using it again**. That's all

C++'s `new` and `delete` also call initialization and finalization routines in the form of the the appropriate constructor or destructor. I won't say "that's all" about that because there are some details in *that* business.

So, to use dynamic allocation successfully you should

- Ask for the memory you need *before* you try to use it, and check that you actually got some (the OS could say "No, you can't have it." you know)
- Insure that you initialize it (either write the right constructor in c++ or manage it yourself in c)
- Don't lose track of it.
- Insure that you manage any needed cleanup before giving it back (destructors in c++, by hand in c). This is probably the hardest part of the whole business.
- Never use memory *after* you've given it back

Answer (score 0):

C `malloc` simply allocates memory, but doesn't "construct" an object. In C++, you would typically use `new`, which does allocate and construct the object. The primary difference is `new` calls the constructor after allocating the RAM. `malloc` is just a 'dumb' memory manager, but may perform better for certain specific cases where you need non-typed raw memory.

Both `new` and `malloc` "return" a pointer. A pointer is an address. So this is the form of both, they are assignment expressions.

```
Coordinate * notObject = (Coordinate*)malloc(sizeof(Coordinate));
Coordinate * object = new Coordinate();
```

Note, `malloc` returns a `void *`, so you must cast it. `new` is typed, so there is no casting required.

Answer (score 0):

> - How does the line that allocates new memory for myList and then adds the new item to it have to look like? Could you please show me a working example for C and C++?

There are actually two different options: You can either create an array of `Coordinate` objects using:

```
Coordinate *list = new Coordinate[ 42 ]; // list can hold at most 42 objects
```

Or, use a linked list, which of course will require you to change the definition of your `Coordinate` data-type:

```
typedef Coordinate_t {
    int x, y;
    Coordinate_t *next;
};
```

Inserting in a linked list is a bit more complicated.

Of course, if you are using C, you cannot use the `new` operator, but will instead have to use `malloc`:

```
Coordinate *list = malloc(*list * 42); /* list can hold at most 42 objects */
```

> - How exactly does malloc in C work? There are some things about it that I'm not familiar with (there is some sort of pointer before the function, and the variable that is allocated is set to mallocs return value)

The allocation function uses some OS specific API to request some memory from the free store (and hence this is therefore implementation dependent). E.g: On *nix, a system API called `sbrk` and friends are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct
{
int x;
int y;
} Coordinate;

Coordinate* myList = 0;

int myListLength = 0;  // initialize myListLength to size of myList

void AddSomething ( int x, int y )
{
    int i;
    // malloc returns a void pointer, so we cast it to be a Coordinate *
    Coordinate* newList = (Coordinate*)malloc(sizeof(Coordinate)*(myListLength+1));
    for(i=0; i < myListLength; ++i) {
        newList[i] = myList[i];
    }
    newList[myListLength].x = x;
    newList[myListLength].y = y;
    if(myList)
        free(myList);
    myList = newList;
    ++myListLength;
 }
```

Note that it's a much better idea to use std::vector if you can.